Adding line and polygon feature into the panoramas in Pano2VR
Is it possible to get the line and polygon feature into the panoramas by using GIS, Pano2VR, and any additional software or apps? I mean adding the line and polygon features to the panoramas inside Pano2VR. I have no idea if this works because, in my understanding, the 360-panos do not have spatial reference. So geodata "doesn't know" where to place itself inside the panos. However, somehow it should work. I don't mean adding hotspots or lines manually inside Pano2VR but automatically adding complex lines and polygons.
